# How do I create a list of youtube video titles from a list of video ids?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using Google Takeout, I have downloaded all of my playlists into a .csv. They have the columns "video id" and "time added". I want to get the corresponding video names for the list of ids. How do I do that?

Comment: This question is not programming related it is related to the usage of the [Google takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout?pli=1) feature within a users google account.    It should not be tagged API unless you are actually using the apis in a programming manner.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint. By requesting `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID_0,VIDEO_ID_1,...,VIDEO_ID_49&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You will find the titles in the answer in the field under `snippet` named `title`.

Please note that you can only request at most 50 titles per request.

Comment: author issuing google takeout they are not using an api.  this will not help them.